# How can I get 3D depth points distance?

Tags: ros, camera-depth-points, 3dcamera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there!

I'm trying to get the depth points distance from 3D sensor (Action Pro).
I already got message sensor_msgs/Image from topic /camera/depth/image_raw.
and I play with sensor_msgs/Image->data. but I don't know how can i get the distance data about each pixel.

thanks guys.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/222190/how-can-i-get-3d-depth-points-distance?/) by [haryngod](https://answers.ros.org/users/25155/haryngod/) on ROS Answers with karma: 30 on 2015-12-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you check [this](http://answers.ros.org/question/125241/how-to-use-depth-value-from-cameradepthimage/#127121)?

---

Originally posted by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) with karma: 3561 on 2015-12-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [haryngod](https://answers.ros.org/users/25155/haryngod/) on 2015-12-28**:
thank for your kindness.
My coworker find the way to get distance to convert endian.
I'm not sure for the detail but he use topic /camera/depth/image_rect.